# Unable to process binding, push JSON data to ObservableArray using ko.mapping.fromJS

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, knockout.js

Can anybody explain what's wrong in my code, I am new to knockout... So, initially I receive json data from database and it works. Than when I click 'Add some' I want to add(push) same data from database to my observable array. The code below obviously doesn't work. Thanks.
**Error:** Unable to process binding "text: function (){return AdId }"...

**HTML:**

```
<div data-bind="foreach: Ads">     
    <p data-bind="text: AdId"></p>         
</div>

<div data-bind="click: addSome">Add some</div>
```

**MODEL:**

```
function AdListModel() {
var self = this;
self.Ads = ko.mapping.fromJS([]);

self.result = function (model) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(model, self.Ads);
}    

self.InitialData = function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/Home/GetAllAds',
        data: { startPosition: 0, numberOfItems: 2 },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {

            self.result(data); <---- works

        }
    });
}

self.addSome = function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/Home/GetAllAds',
        data: { startPosition: 0, numberOfItems: 2 },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {

            self.Ads.push(data); <---- doesn't work


        },
    });

};

self.InitialData();
}

ko.applyBindings(new AdListModel());
```

I tried `self.Ads.push(ko.mapping.fromJS(data))` - didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems from the error message, that your `model` does not have an `AdId` property.

Can you add a dump of the JSON model returned by your API?

**Edit**

Your `Ads` property should be an `ko.observableArray()` instead of `ko.mapping.fromJS([])`:

```
function AdListModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.Ads = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.result = function (model) {
        ko.mapping.fromJS(model, self.Ads);
    }
```

**Edit 2**

And you have to map the data before pushing it:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '/Home/GetAllAds',
    data: { startPosition: 0, numberOfItems: 2 },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        self.Ads.push(ko.mapping.fromJS(data));
    },
});
```

**Edit 3**

If your JSON looks like this:

```
[
    {"AdId":1,"AdContent":"test1"},
    {"AdId":2,"AdContent":"test2"}
]
```

Then it is an Array and you have to iterate over each entries:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '/Home/GetAllAds',
    data: { startPosition: 0, numberOfItems: 2 },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        data.forEach(function(d) {
            self.Ads.push(ko.mapping.fromJS(d));
        });
    },
});
```

Comment: [{"AdId":1,"AdContent":"test1"},{"AdId":2,"AdContent":"test2"},.......], but initially it works, it doesn't work when I want to add the same data on click.

Comment: No this doesn't work, I tried change self.Ads(data) and on click self.Ads.push(data). nothing.

Comment: see edit, you have to map your data before pushing it to your array. You are currently pushing raw data to your observable array.

Comment: From your question, it looks like you've tried my solution :( Can you post a sample of the JSON coming back from your server ? Is it an object or an Array?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your model. It looks like it is an array, so you have to iterate over each entries. See Edit 3...

Comment: [{"AdId":1,"AdContent":"test1"},{"AdId":2,"AdContent":"test2"},{"AdId":3,"AdContent":"test3"}] - array of objects

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much!